# assign a random number to the variable

Tags: bash

Normally, I may use the following expression to define a variable in bash as the number

```
var='3'
```

How could I associate the variable with the random value, e.g. from 1 to 6, which could be assigned each time in the for loop:

```
for var ...; do
 print $var
done
```

Assuming that in each iteration, the var should be randomly selected from 1 to 6.

Comment: https://xkcd.com/221/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if your question is about generating the random number

```
$ echo $(( RANDOM % 6 + 1 ))
4  # results may vary
```

or getting a sequence of random numbers. A C-style `for` loop would probably be simplest.

```
# Roll a 6-sided dice 5 times.
for ((n=0; var=RANDOM%6+1, n<5; n++)); do
   echo $var
done
```

The second expression makes use of the `,` operator, so that both `var` is assigned to just before the beginning of each loop iteration.

(Or course, there's not much reason to write the loop this way. Be clear, and put the assignment at the top of the body instead.

```
for ((n=0; n < 5; n++)); do
    var=$((RANDOM%6 + 1))
    echo $var
done
```

)

Comment: `for var in  $(( RANDOM % 6 + 1 )){,,,,,} ;do ...`

Comment: The C-style loop scales better.

Comment: Of course, but as we have no idea about  target to reach, for some use cases, this syntax could be simpler

Comment: Anyway, your C-Style loop do contain a bug: try to `unset var` before running them! You have to set `var=`  **before** test (`n<5`): `unset var ;for ((n=0;var=RANDOM%6+1, n<5; n++ )); do    echo $var; done`

Comment: Hm, good point. Of course, the more I think about it, there's not reason for the assignment to be in this part of the loop other than to mimic the OP's idea of having the loop itself assign to `var.` It would be clearer to just make `var=$((RANDOM%6+1))` the first line of the loop body.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need for `for loop` actually, you can do it by using `RANDOM`.
If we take your example into consideration;
To create random number between 1 and 6, you can use something like;

```
$(( ( $RANDOM % 6 ) + 1))
```

You can try it with;

```
random_number=$(( ( $RANDOM % 6 ) + 1)); echo $random_number
```

Comment: does it mean that randon_number would be any number in the given range in each call of the variable e.g. using echo $random_number or alternatively in each assignemnt of the variable (so it should be in FOR loop) ?

Comment: `random_number` is fixed by the assignment; `RANDOM` is a special shell parameter whose value can (and usually will) change each time you access its value.